# Phonegap/Cordova App display too big and event not work in some device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

My Phonegap/Cordova + Angular JS app looks fine with the setting below, on devices like Lenovo A369 i , Sony Experia M ,Samsung S3 ,etc .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height , target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

But the display too big in Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (720 x 1280)  , and there're some event not work in Tablet like angular iscroll ( http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-iScroll ) to make pull to refresh , and  swap left righ gesture with angular gesture ( https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures ).

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

Comment: without  target-densitydpi=device-dpi the display will be blurry

Comment: http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/

Comment: http://sunpig.com/martin/2012/03/18/goldilocks-and-the-three-device-pixel-ratios/

Comment: so is there an alternative to prevent image blurry without target-density ?

Comment: use css media query device pixel ratio

Comment: are you have a tutroial about this and how implement in phonegap ?

Comment: http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1127120282/pixel-perfect-android-web-ui Demo in this link or serarch about mediaquery for android

Comment: best tutorial by http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html